# Tic tac toe finding win?

Tags: swift

I am making a tic tac toe game in Swift for 2 players.  Now I know I can find a winner by making outlets for the 9 buttons and then writing for all the 3 in row cases, but I was wondering if there is a better way to do this? And is there a better way to write my switch statement?

```
@IBOutlet weak var button1: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var button2: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var button3: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var button4: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var button5: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var button6: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var button7: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var button8: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var button9: UIButton!
var player = 1

@IBAction func playersTurn(sender: UIButton){

    switch player{
        case 1: sender.setTitle("X", forState: UIControlState.Normal); player = 2;break;
        case 2: sender.setTitle("O", forState: UIControlState.Normal); player = 1;break;
        default:exit(0); break
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you not use an array instead of 9 separate buttons?  While you have 9 separate names to check, you probably won't be able to improve things very much over writing out 8 triplets of 'if buttonA is same as buttonB and buttonA is the same as buttonC' for the relevant sets of names.

Comment: You don't need the switch at all.  How about `sender.setTitle(["", "X", "O"][player], forState: .Normal); player = 3 - player`

Answer (score 2):

I would set the `tag` property on your buttons using values 0-9 in order from top to bottom, left to right, like so:

```
[ 0 ][ 1 ][ 2 ]
[ 3 ][ 4 ][ 5 ]
[ 6 ][ 7 ][ 8 ]
```

Then create a model to represent each square and give it a corresponding index value, as well as a reference to the player who owns it.  Then you can handle you game logic with those models and update the UI by getting references to your buttons with `viewForTag(_:)`.  Here's my version:

```
class Square {
    var owningPlayer: Player?

    let index: Int
    init( index: Int ) {
        self.index = index
    }
}

class Player {
    let symbol: String

    init( symbol: String ) {
        self.symbol = symbol
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var squares = [Square]()
    var players = [Player]()

    var currentPlayer: Player?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.players = [ Player(symbol: "X"), Player(symbol: "O") ]
        self.currentPlayer = self.players[0]

        // Create squares
        for i in 0..<9 {
            self.squares.append( Square(index: i) )
        }
    }

    @IBAction func buttonPressed( button: UIButton ) {
        guard let player = self.currentPlayer else {
            fatalError( "Don't have a current player!" )
        }

        if let square = self.squares.filter({ $0.index == button.tag }).first {

            // Update model
            square.owningPlayer = player

            // Update UI
            button.setTitle( player.symbol, forState: .Normal )

        }

        if self.checkWin() {
            print( "\(player.symbol) wins!" )
        }
        else {
            self.currentPlayer = self.players.filter({ $0 !== player }).first
        }
    }

    func checkWin() -> Bool {
        guard let player = self.currentPlayer else {
            fatalError( "Don't have a current player!" )
        }

        let winningSequences = [
            // Horizontal rows
            [ 0, 1, 2 ],
            [ 3, 4, 5 ],
            [ 6, 7, 8 ],
            // Diagonals
            [ 0, 4, 8 ],
            [ 2, 4, 6 ],
            // Vertical rows
            [ 0, 3, 6 ],
            [ 1, 4, 7 ],
            [ 2, 5, 8 ],
        ]

        // Get indexes owned by this player
        let selectedIndexes = self.squares.filter({ $0.owningPlayer === player }).map { $0.index }

        // Change the sequence arrays into sets for accurate comparison using `contains(_:)`
        if winningSequences.map({ Set<Int>($0) }).contains( Set<Int>(selectedIndexes) ) {
            return true
        }

        return false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although @Patrick Lynch's answer is excellent I found that it didn't match a win should the game go beyond 3 moves.

This is because he is only checking if any of the winningSequences contains a current move sequence (selectedIndexes). As the winningSequences map only has a max of 3 items it'll never contain a set of 4 moves.

To resolve this I changed contains to subset. i.e is a winningSequence (0, 1, 2) a subset of the selectedIndexes (0, 5, 1, 2)

Replace

```
if winningSequences.map({ Set<Int>($0) }).contains( Set<Int>(selectedIndexes) ) { 
 return true 
}
```

with

```
for seq in winningSequences.map( { Set<Int>($0)}) {
  if seq.isSubset(of: selectedIndexes) {
     return true
     }
  }
```

I'm still new to swift so if I'm wrong or anyone has a better idea then I'd be happy to hear it.

Comment: If you give `winninSequences` the type `[Set<Int>]` to begin with, you don't need to convert them to sets (also applies to the other answer).